Magento 2 cloudflare unable to install Matomo
We are using magento 2 with Cloudflare enabled on the website but when we try to install Matomo getting this issue on the browser console -
index.php:1 Refused to load the script 'https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/vcd15cbe7772f49c399c6a5babf22c124171
    7689176015' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: 
    "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not 
    explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

And
It is not proper to install getting this SQLSTATE error -

Does anyone know how to solve this?

You'll need to modify your Content Security Policy (wherever that is actually set/configured), to include https://static.cloudflareinsights.com as a valid source.

@CBroe is correct, you need to modify the Content Security Policy of your web server apache/nginx. You can also check your current Content Security Policy here: https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/

You need to whitelist the cloudflare domaine in a csp_whitelist.xml.
for more details, you can check the Magento 2 donc https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/
